# Javscipt go from one index to another

Tags: javascript, indexing

what would be the JavaScript syntax for going from one index number to another? I'm asking JavaScript equivalent of this Python code: `c[3:6]`

What I eventually want to do is to append "A" list of 100 values to list "B", then make a counter increment by 100, so when the user clicks on a button, the counter increments and the list of A is now appended to the list B's index from 100th to 200th. And this goes on like that every time the user clicks on the button.

```
var counter = 0;

var means = [];
var hundredmeans = [];
var growingmeans = [];
var popMean=100;
var standard = gaussian(popMean, 5); 

function makeAndPlotManySamples()
    {
        var sample = [];
        for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
            for (j = 0; j<sampleSize; j++){
                sample[i] = standard()
            }
            hundredmeans[i] = average(sample)
        }

        growingmeans[counter::counter+100].append = (hundredmeans)
        
        var trace = {
            x: sample,
            name: 'Data',
            type: 'histogram',
            xbins: {
                end: 120,
                size: 0.05,
                start: 80
            }
        };
        var layout = {
            xaxis:{
                title: 'One of the one hundred samples',
                range: [80, 120]
            },
            yaxis: {range:[0,Math.max(10,Math.floor(sampleSize/10))]}
        };
        var data3 = [trace];
        Plotly.newPlot('oneSample', data3, layout);
        var trace2 = {
            x: growingmeans,
            name:'Data',
            type: 'histogram',
            xbins: {
                end: 120,
                size: 0.05,
                start: 80
                }
            };
        var layout2 = {
            xaxis: {
                title: 'The distribution of the  means of the samples',
                range: [80, 120]
                },
                yaxis:{range:[0,30]}
            };
        var data4 = [trace2];
    
        Plotly.newPlot('sampleMeans', data4,layout2);
        counter=counter+100; 
            };
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Thank you for the help. Slice is not helpful at this point. I made some edits to the question to make it more specific what I need to do.

Comment: Share some sample data, what is the structure list "A" and "B"? What should your expected output look like after apend?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just added a piece of code. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: The code you shared doesn't help. Read my previous comment again

Comment: You can think of "sample" as a random number, "hundredmeans" as a list of 100 random "sample"s and the "growingmeans" is as another list which is appended "hundredmeans" with each counter increase. Does that explain well?